# StackExchange™ ChronoWarping ChatCombinator™

Tags: feature-request, chat

As chat has grown in its awesomeness I find that I would like to participate in multiple chat rooms across multiple sites.

For example I would like to be in a few StackOverflow rooms and few Meta rooms.

However, I don't want to have to open a gazzilion pages to participate.

Are there any plans to allow me to go to one Chat MultiCollider, where I can participate in chats across various network sites.

Comment: I blame popular demand.

Comment: And people wonder why the duplicate post detector has so many false negatives

Answer (score 4):

Yes, chat.stackexchange.com is being worked on and will support global auth, so anyone with 20 rep on any network site can participate there.

That said, we will still have:

- chat.stackoverflow.com
- chat.serverfault.com
- chat.superuser.com
- chat.stackexchange.com

... at a minimum.